# Division of divs heigh in row

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, division

Id like to have two divs infront of each other. The problem is, that Id like to division the heigh of the right column /6. It is because there are six divs in the right, which works like buttons. How should I do it? I know it is posible to use flexbox, but then, how would I tell it to division the heigh?

Also, I found javascript solution for same heigh divs, should I add just some simple code to division the heigh? THank you for advice

```
 HTML
//left side
    <div id="columnOne">
    </div>

//right side (height of left side /6
    <div class="columnTwo">
    </div>
    <div class="columnTwo">
    </div>
    <div class="columnTwo">
    </div>
    <div class="columnTwo">
    </div>
    <div class="columnTwo">
    </div>
    <div class="columnTwo">
    </div>


    // Javascript
    $(".columnTwo").height($("#columnOne").height()
```

);

Comment: Oh yep, sorry, my code looks completely diferent, I just used this as simplification  of the problem and coppied the code from other thread..I have edited it, it is good right now.

@ObsidianAge

Comment: Awesome; glad to hear that was just a slight oversight :) Keep in mind that you'll also need to update your jQuery to match the new classes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox, and insert each column in a different div:

```
 <div class="columns">

 <div class="columnOne">
 </div>

 <div class="columnTwo">
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

With this css:

```
.columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}

.columnTwo {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.columnTwo > div {
 /* w/e you want */
 flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it has no javascript involved!

Comment: I thought it is necesarry. This is solution without javascript and I take it like far better way of solving the problem.